# Edit page header on a custom plugin

Tags: plugins, customization, wp-admin, headers

I am writing a custom plugin for Wordpress but how in the world do I edit the page header? I need to add some javascript and related codes there.

Comment: you want the plugin to add javascript to header of site pages or the admin page?

Comment: Yes that is correct. How is this possible?

Comment: To add javascript code to the header of the admin page. So the plugin settings page in the wp-admin.

Answer (score 1):

> #### NOTE
>
> This code will load those scripts on all admin pages. Better you go through the Codex examples to get an idea how you can [load the scripts on pages of specific plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style#Examples)

Here's the code to load the custom scripts on admin pages

```
function wpse60745_loadto_admin() {

    // to load styles
    wp_register_style( 'my_plugin_css', plugins_url('plugin-style.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_plugin_css' );

    //to load javascripts
    wp_register_script( 'my_plugin_js', plugins_url('plugin.js', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_plugin_js' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse60745_loadto_admin');
```

<sup>Above code is updated</sup>

***Reference***

- [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)
- [`wp_enque_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)